# Question about ecv: Modify the size of ecvPortrait (image and frame placeholder)

Tags: cv, ecv

The class is available [here](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/ecv/ecv.dtx) and a template [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/ecv-curriculum-vitae-english-version).
In the class, the following command, defines the image environment.

```
% Command to layout the portrait (must be 60mmx40mm) 
\newcommand\ecv@Portrait[1]{%
  %% A frame as placeholder (with  some 1mm inner padding):
  \pgfrect[stroke]{\pgfxy(6.85,0.65)}{\pgfxy(4.3,-6.3)}
  %% Actually a concrete digital image:
  \pgfdeclareimage[interpolate=true,height=60mm,width=40mm]{portrait}{#1}
  \pgfputat{\pgfxy(6.77,0.5)}{\pgfbox[left,top]{\pgfuseimage{portrait}}}
}
```

Below I have a minimal example. How can I overload with my settings the image environment? E.g., modify the image size to 50mmx40mm and the frame accordingly as well.

```
%%
%% Copyright 2006-2011 Christoph P. Neumann, Bernd Haberstumpf
%%
%% This LaTeX file provides a template for a german CV.
%%
%% This file is free property; as a special exception the author
%% gives unlimited permission to copy and/or distribute it, with
%% or without modifications, as long as this notice is
%% preserved.
%%
%% This file is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
%% but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law;
%% without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or
%% FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
%%

\documentclass[english]{ecv}
\usepackage{blindtext}
% Dateiname: images/<portrait>.jpg
\ecvPortrait{portrait}
\ecvName{<Surname(s), Name>}

\begin{document}

\begin{ecv}

%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Person
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvPerson}{\ecvPerson}}

\ecvEPR{Name}   {\textsc{<Name>}, <Surname(s)>}
\ecvEPR{Addresse}{<House number> <Street>\ecvNewLine
                 <City>, <Postcode>, <Country>}
\ecvEPR{Telephone}{<Area code>--<Telephone number>}
\ecvEPR{Fax}{<Area code>--<Faxnumber>}
\ecvEPR{E-Mail} {\ecvHyperEMail{<E-Mail>}}
\ecvEPR{Nationality}
                {<Nationality>}
\ecvEPR{Date of birth}
                {<Date of birth>}

\ecvBSec{Objective}
\ecvEFR{}{\blindtext[1]}                

%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Profession
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvProfession}{\ecvProfession}}

% Chronologisch beginnend mit den juengsten Beschaeftigungen
\ecvEFR{Period}{<Year>--<Year>}
\ecvENR{Employer}
                {\ecvBold{<Company name>}\\
                 <House number><Street>, <City>, <Postcode>, <Country>}
%
\ecvEFR{Project <From> until <To>}
                {<Topic>}
\ecvENR{Position}{<Position held>}
\ecvENR{Main responsibilities}
                {<List of activities>}

%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Education
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvEducation}{\ecvEducation}}

% Universit"at
\ecvEFR{Period}{<Year>--<Year>}
\ecvENR{Accquired qualifications}
                {\ecvBold{<Title>}}
\ecvENR{Institute}
                {<Name of educational institution>}
\ecvENR{Principal subjects}
                {<List of the major subjects>}
\ecvENR{Minor subjects}
                {<List of minor subjects>}
\ecvENR{Grade}   {Avarage grade <overall avarage grade>}
% Schule
\ecvEFR{Period}{<Year>--<Year>}
\ecvENR{Accquired qualifications}
                {<Title>}
\ecvENR{Graduate school}
                {<Name of the school>}

%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Research
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvResearch}{\ecvResearch}}

\ecvEFB{Diploma thesis}{"`<Title of the diploma thesis>"' --- <Institute>}
\ecvEFB{Seminar paper}{"`<Title of the seminar paper>"' 
                      --- <Institute>}

%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Publications
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvPublications}{\ecvPublications}}

\ecvEFR{Publication}{<Author>:
                     \emph{<Title of the publication>}
                     <Name of the journal>. <Publisher>, 
                     <City>, <Year>}



%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Jobs
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvJobs}{\ecvJobs}}

\ecvEFR{Period}{<Year>--<Year>}
\ecvENR{Employer}
                 {\ecvBold{<Name of the Company>}, <City>/<Country>}
\ecvENR{Employment}
                 {<Type of the employment>}
\ecvENR{Main responsibilities}
                 {<List of activities>
                 }

%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Languages
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvLanguages}{\ecvLanguages}}

\ecvERSub{First language}{\ecvBold{English}}

\ecvEBSub{Other languages}
                        {<Language> -- Read: <Degree>, Write: 
                         <Degree>, Talk: <Degree>}

%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Language Travels
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvBSub{\ecvLanguageTravels}

\ecvEFR{Period}{<Date>--<Date>}
\ecvENR{Place} {<City>/<Country>}
\ecvENR{Vendor}
                {<Organizer>}
\ecvENR{Certificate}
                {<Name of the accquired certificate>}


%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Abilities
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvPageBreak
\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvAbilities}{\ecvAbilities}}
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Abilities / social
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvEBSub{Social Skills}
                {<Description of the social strengths>
                }
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Abilities / organisational
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvEBSub{Organisational Skills}
                {<Description of organisational skills>
                }
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Abilities / professional
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvBEBSub{Technical Skills}
                {<Description of technical skills>}
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Hobbies
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvBEBSub{Hobbies}
                {<List of major hobbies and private interests>
                }

%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Attachments
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvAttachements}{\ecvAttachements}}

\ecvOVR         {<Lsit of all attachements>
                } 

\end{ecv}

%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Signature
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvSig{<Name>, <Surname(s)>}{<City>}

\end{document}
\end
```

Comment: Can you edit the title of your question to reflect what your question is about? This would help future users who face the same problem to find your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\renewcommand\ecv@Portrait[1]{...}` to overwrite the definition of `\ecv@Portrait`

```
%%
%% Copyright 2006-2011 Christoph P. Neumann, Bernd Haberstumpf
%%
%% This LaTeX file provides a template for a german CV.
%%
%% This file is free property; as a special exception the author
%% gives unlimited permission to copy and/or distribute it, with
%% or without modifications, as long as this notice is
%% preserved.
%%
%% This file is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
%% but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law;
%% without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or
%% FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
%%

\documentclass[english]{ecv}
\usepackage{blindtext}
% Dateiname: images/<portrait>.jpg
\ecvPortrait{portrait}
\ecvName{<Surname(s), Name>}

\makeatletter
% Command to layout the portrait (must be 60mmx40mm) 
\renewcommand\ecv@Portrait[1]{%
  %% A frame as placeholder (with  some 1mm inner padding):
  \pgfrect[stroke]{\pgfxy(6.85,0.65)}{\pgfxy(4.3,-5.3)}
  %% Actually a concrete digital image:
  \pgfdeclareimage[interpolate=true,height=50mm,width=40mm]{portrait}{#1}
  \pgfputat{\pgfxy(6.77,0.5)}{\pgfbox[left,top]{\pgfuseimage{portrait}}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{ecv}

%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Person
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvPerson}{\ecvPerson}}

\ecvEPR{Name}   {\textsc{<Name>}, <Surname(s)>}
\ecvEPR{Addresse}{<House number> <Street>\ecvNewLine
                 <City>, <Postcode>, <Country>}
\ecvEPR{Telephone}{<Area code>--<Telephone number>}
\ecvEPR{Fax}{<Area code>--<Faxnumber>}
\ecvEPR{E-Mail} {\ecvHyperEMail{<E-Mail>}}
\ecvEPR{Nationality}
                {<Nationality>}
\ecvEPR{Date of birth}
                {<Date of birth>}

\ecvBSec{Objective}
\ecvEFR{}{\blindtext[1]}                

%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Profession
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvProfession}{\ecvProfession}}

% Chronologisch beginnend mit den juengsten Beschaeftigungen
\ecvEFR{Period}{<Year>--<Year>}
\ecvENR{Employer}
                {\ecvBold{<Company name>}\\
                 <House number><Street>, <City>, <Postcode>, <Country>}
%
\ecvEFR{Project <From> until <To>}
                {<Topic>}
\ecvENR{Position}{<Position held>}
\ecvENR{Main responsibilities}
                {<List of activities>}

%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Education
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvEducation}{\ecvEducation}}

% Universit"at
\ecvEFR{Period}{<Year>--<Year>}
\ecvENR{Accquired qualifications}
                {\ecvBold{<Title>}}
\ecvENR{Institute}
                {<Name of educational institution>}
\ecvENR{Principal subjects}
                {<List of the major subjects>}
\ecvENR{Minor subjects}
                {<List of minor subjects>}
\ecvENR{Grade}   {Avarage grade <overall avarage grade>}
% Schule
\ecvEFR{Period}{<Year>--<Year>}
\ecvENR{Accquired qualifications}
                {<Title>}
\ecvENR{Graduate school}
                {<Name of the school>}

%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Research
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvResearch}{\ecvResearch}}

\ecvEFB{Diploma thesis}{"`<Title of the diploma thesis>"' --- <Institute>}
\ecvEFB{Seminar paper}{"`<Title of the seminar paper>"' 
                      --- <Institute>}

%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Publications
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvPublications}{\ecvPublications}}

\ecvEFR{Publication}{<Author>:
                     \emph{<Title of the publication>}
                     <Name of the journal>. <Publisher>, 
                     <City>, <Year>}



%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Jobs
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvJobs}{\ecvJobs}}

\ecvEFR{Period}{<Year>--<Year>}
\ecvENR{Employer}
                 {\ecvBold{<Name of the Company>}, <City>/<Country>}
\ecvENR{Employment}
                 {<Type of the employment>}
\ecvENR{Main responsibilities}
                 {<List of activities>
                 }

%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Languages
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvLanguages}{\ecvLanguages}}

\ecvERSub{First language}{\ecvBold{English}}

\ecvEBSub{Other languages}
                        {<Language> -- Read: <Degree>, Write: 
                         <Degree>, Talk: <Degree>}

%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Language Travels
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvBSub{\ecvLanguageTravels}

\ecvEFR{Period}{<Date>--<Date>}
\ecvENR{Place} {<City>/<Country>}
\ecvENR{Vendor}
                {<Organizer>}
\ecvENR{Certificate}
                {<Name of the accquired certificate>}


%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Abilities
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvPageBreak
\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvAbilities}{\ecvAbilities}}
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Abilities / social
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvEBSub{Social Skills}
                {<Description of the social strengths>
                }
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Abilities / organisational
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvEBSub{Organisational Skills}
                {<Description of organisational skills>
                }
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Abilities / professional
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvBEBSub{Technical Skills}
                {<Description of technical skills>}
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Hobbies
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvBEBSub{Hobbies}
                {<List of major hobbies and private interests>
                }

%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Attachments
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvAttachements}{\ecvAttachements}}

\ecvOVR         {<Lsit of all attachements>
                } 

\end{ecv}

%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Signature
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvSig{<Name>, <Surname(s)>}{<City>}

\end{document}
```

[image]